# get file list of files contained in a zip file

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I have a zip archive: `my_zip.zip`. **Inside it is one txt file, the name of which I do not know.** I was taking a look at Python's `zipfile` module ( http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html ), but couldn't make too much sense of what I'm trying to do.

How would I do the equivalent of 'double-clicking' the zip file to get the txt file and then use the txt file so I can do:

```
>>> f = open('my_txt_file.txt','r')
>>> contents = f.read()
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

What you need is `ZipFile.namelist()` that will give you a list of all the contents of the archive, you can then do a `zip.open('filename_you_discover')` to get the contents of that file.

Comment: Or use [`infolist()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) if you want to get other details; like the Date Modified or Compressed Size

Comment: Is there a method that returns the file names as an iterator rather than a list?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/berezovskyi/c440125e10fc013a36f6f5feb8bc3117 is a short hack I wrote for myself to use a generator as `for f in itertar(tarfile):`

Answer (score 74):

```
import zipfile

# zip file handler  
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('filename.zip')

# list available files in the container
print (zip.namelist())

# extract a specific file from the zip container
f = zip.open("file_inside_zip.txt")

# save the extraced file 
content = f.read()
f = open('file_inside_zip.extracted.txt', 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 25):

```
import zipfile

zip = zipfile.ZipFile('my_zip.zip')
f = zip.open('my_txt_file.txt')
contents = f.read()
f.close()
```

You can see the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html). In particular, the `namelist()` method will give you the names of the zip file members.

Comment: I get an error saying that "There is no item named '<filename>' in the archive". Note that I **do not know** what the name of the file that is zipped is called (and it is different than the name of the zip archive).