# How to retrieve the contents of a zip file in python once the zip file is uploaded using HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am creating a webapp and one feature of that includes user to upload a zip file. I want to save those contents in my server side and use them for some task. I am not able to achieve the same, I can only access the names of the files and not actual files. I am a newbie in python programming so help please. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get file list of files contained in a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844781/get-file-list-of-files-contained-in-a-zip-file)

Comment: This is possible I guess when the zip resides in my system. When someone uploads the Zip file where does it get stored on the server?? Will those answers work for me ?