# Viewing the files contained in a .gz archive using python

Tags: python-3.x, archive, extract, gzip

I am looking for a simple way to view the contents (file names) of a `.gz` archive. I saw that there has been a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844781/get-file-list-of-files-contained-in-a-zip-file) already on how to do this when using `.zip` archive. So basically I am looking for the analogue of [`ZipFile.namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist), but for `.gz` archives.

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592099/how-do-i-list-contents-of-a-gz-file-without-extracting-it-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gz` files are *not*, in and of themselves, archives. A `.gz` file contains a single compressed file. When you decompress `foo.bar.gz`, you get the file `foo.bar`. So there's your one name, in the name of the `.gz` file itself.

You might have a `.tar.gz` file, which is a TAR (tape archive) file containing a representation of a directory of files, that is then compressed as a single file by gzip. In that case, you would need to use Python's `tarfile` to read the file and list the contents.